# Why the following set has no extreme points?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

***Question:***
Consider the set $ = \{(, ): || ≤ 1\}$ is.   Then
(i) $$ has no extreme point as it is not convex.
(ii) $$ has no extreme point as it is not closed.
(iii) $$ has no extreme point as it is bounded.
(iv) $$ has infinitely many extreme points.

I can say that $$ does not contain any extreme point, as any point $(1,y)$ can be written as a convex combination of $(1,y-1)$ and $(1,y+1)$. Another reason can be that $$ being a closed convex set, contains at least one straight line (vertical) and so $$ has no extreme point.

But what can be the reason among (i), (ii) and (iii)? I see none of them is correct.

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of the terms that are used?  Is the set convex, closed, bounded?  Are those required or prohibited for sets with extreme points?

Comment: Hi! I've taken the expedient of editing your title so that it's less shouty. I'm sure you didn't mean anything by it (other than your puzzlement, I imagine), but it can seem somewhat harsh.

Comment: @RossMillikan obviously the set is convex, closed. I can say bounded horizontally but unbounded vertically. although a bounded set can have extreme points.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but none of the alternatives are correct.

Comment: I have no idea why there is a downvote for this question. I raised a question, explained my part and asked for a solution.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Lots of folks downvote with no ostensible reason, its annoying but best to ignore.